# Question on the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n} = -\ln(1-x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

$f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n} = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + ... = -\ln(1-x)$ for $|x| < 1$.

$f'(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 +... = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x| < 1$

If $f'(x) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{1-x}$, then $f(x) = \displaystyle\int\frac{1}{1-x}dx$

But $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{1-x}dx = -\ln(1-x) + C$, and so $f(x) = -\ln(1-x) + C$

Do we need a definite integral here so there will be no $C$ and will agree with how $f(x)$ was originally defined? If so what would the definite integral be? Or maybe there is no definite integral at all?

Comment: Everything is good. You only need to prove that $C=0$ - it follows from the fact that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: You're right: $f'(x)=\frac1{1-x}$, so $f(x)$ must be $-\ln(1-x)+C$ for some $C$. Now, to find what $C$ is, try letting $x$ be $0$ and solving for $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: $f'(x)=\frac1{1-x}$, so $f(x)$ must be $-\ln(1-x)+C$ for some $C$. Now, to find what $C$ is, try letting $x$ be $0$ and solving for $C$.

Or, if you want to do a definite integral, start with:
$$1+t+t^2+\dotsb=\frac1{1-t}$$
Take the definite integral from $0$ to $x$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^x(1+t+t^2+\dotsb)\operatorname d\!t&=\int_0^x\frac1{1-t}\operatorname d\!t\\
x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\dotsb&=-\ln(1-x)
\end{align}

---

Note that if we take $x=-1$, we get the famous series for $\ln2$:
$$\ln2=1-\frac12+\frac13-\dotsb$$
which can be proven without calculus if you try hard enough.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is clear now.

Comment: (On the last note: There is only one number, $e$, such that $e^x\ge x+1$ for all $x$. This can be taken as the _definition_ of $e$—since our goal is to prove something without calculus, it makes sense to use a definition that doesn't use calculus. This can be proven equivalent to the other definitions.)

Answer (score 0):

There are various things going on here. One is the issue of the $+C.$ What you wrote might better be put

> If $f'(x) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{1-x}$, then *by definition* of the indefinite integral $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{1-x}dx=f(x)+C$

Also , by definition of definite integrals

If $f'(x) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{1-x}$, on $[a,b]$ then $ \displaystyle\int_a^b\frac{1}{1-t}dt=f(b)-f(a)$

Note that an arbitrarily chosen constant of integration $C$ will cancel out.

I changed the variable of integration so that I could say that for $|x| \lt 1,$ $$\int_0^x\frac1{1-t}dt=-\ln(1-t)\mid_0^x=\left(-\ln(1-x)\right)-(-\ln(1-0))=\ln\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)-0$$

There is also the matter of term by term integration and differentiation of power series. Notice that this is one of the interesting cases where

$f(x) = = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + ... = -\ln(1-x)$ for $|x| < 1$ and also $x=-1$ but not $x=1.$

$f'(x) =  1 + x + x^2 + x^3 +... = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x| < 1$ but not for  $x= -1$ or $x=1.$